# Unable to delete document in mongodb using php driver

Tags: php, mongodb

Here is the structure of my document in mongo.

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "52c7ab89e4b079616e8e4be4"
},
"memberId": 1,
"memberName": "Hannan Shaik",
"memberEmail": "XXX@example.com",
"memberPhone": "123456"
}
```

PHP Code to remove this record is

```
$memberId=1;
$collection->remove(array('memberId' => $memberId), array("safe" => true));
```

This is not removing the document. Whereas, below statement does.

```
 $collection->remove(array('memberId' => 1), array("safe" => true));
```

Kindly explain as to what is the cause for this?

Please note I cannot directly give the memberId value as the above statement is written in a function that is passed with a value in $memberId.

Comment: So, `$memberId` is created using a function? Are you **100%** sure that it is a number? And I do mean 100% sure. Much time is wasted here because people do not bother with details.

Comment: Oops.. You were right. The $memberId was populated by value from $_POST. Thus it was a string. Now its working. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a miss to check if the $member was a number or string.

The value is $member was a string. Hence the issue.

Thanks @Sverri M. Olsen

Comment: `$memberId=1;` is not a string AFAIK.